# Visual Studio 2010, how to remove $(ProjectDir) from include path?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

My VC++ project is configured so that all source files are in $(ProjectDir)\source\ (which is in the include path).  The annoyance is that somehow it seems that $(ProjectDir) is automatically put in the include path... which isn't a huge deal, every time I write a #include I get an intellisense popup with a lot of directories that don't even have header files in them.  Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In `Project properties --> VC++ directories --> Include Directories` you can manually set your include path without using the `$(ProjectDir)`.

Comment: According to the properties dialog the only things being included are

$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include

Tried setting a property sheet with just these directories to be sure, and there was no effect.

Comment: Uncheck the `Inherit from parent or project defaults` checkbox. The `$(ProjectDir)` is probably included in your main project or `.props` file